# Как правильно организовать связанные таблицы в базе данных MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, реляционная-модель

Существует две таблицы - users и orders:

| id | first_name | orders_amount_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Вася | 5634200 |
| 2 | Петя | 3982830 |

| id | user_id | order_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | 150 |
| 3 | 2 | 70 |
| 4 | 1 | 320 |
| 5 | 2 | 20 |
| 6 | 2 | 10 |
| 7 | 2 | 85 |
| 8 | 1 | 25 |

Таблицы связаны по user id. Задача заключается в том, чтобы для каждого пользователя показывать сумму всех его заказов, их (заказов) может быть тысячи, может быть десятки тысяч, при этом и пользователей одновременно делающих запрос могут быть сотни и тысячи. Есть два варианта:

1. При каждом новом заказе помимо записи в таблицу orders увеличивать счетчик orders_amount_total , а потом просто его показывать пользователю.
2. Убрать поле orders_amount_total вовсе, а чтобы показывать сумму всех заказов JOIN-нить таблицы и использовать оператор SUM чтобы посчитать суммы всех заказов конкретного пользователя.

Какой вариант лучше использовать? Почему? Почему плох другой вариант?

P.S. я считаю что второй вариант лаконичный и правильный, учитывая что БД реляционная, но есть сильные сомнения насчет нагрузки на сервер, ведь выборка при подсчете суммы большая даже для одного пользователя, а их много.

Comment: *Задача заключается в том, чтобы для каждого пользователя показывать сумму всех его заказов* Сумма нужна абсолютно точная, или небольшой плюс-минус (типа округлённо, скажем) не страшен? во втором варианте точная сумма может запрашиваться отдельно.

Comment: Таблица orders - create only? или записи могут корректироваться и удаляться?

Comment: @Akina Нужна точная сумма. В таблицу orders только добавляем записи, не изменяем и не удаляем.

Comment: Если выдача текущей суммы - критичная операция, можете добавить в таблицу юзеров поле с этой суммой, обновляемое по триггеру (и пересчитываемое сервисной процедурой). Конечно, переопределение обычно bad practice, но критичность позволяет такое отступление от правил.

Comment: @Akina ага, понял, а что подразумеваете под сервисной процедурой?

Comment: Некая процедура, выполняемая вручную администратором в рамках сопровождения продукта. Например, как составная часть процедуры восстановления в случае каких-либо сбоев либо процедуры контроля на отсутствие ошибок или нарушений целостности данных...